# Cannot wake up Paz

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've finished all game and now I'm collecting trophies (PS4).
One of the last of them is to get all memento photos. Got 10/11, to get last one I need to give rest to Paz in Medical platform.
My problem is that I gave her one photo and now she's sleeping. I went out, smoked like 5 phantom cigars and she is still sleeping - I can't give her anymore. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried leaving MB and returning?

Comment: Have you given her 10 so far? Do you have the 11th or still looking for it?

Comment: You should leave Mother Base and return. That's the reason why it's recommended to periodically visit Paz over the course of the game, so you don't waste time leaving and returning all the time.

Comment: After re-entering motherbase she wakes up now, thanks. I need to leave MB only once, after that phantom cigar works fine.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Nolonar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/46740/nolonar), you need to leave Mother Base completely in order to progress some MB-based story elements.